# Twitter digits-android: exception 403 error:239

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to implement the sample Twitter Digit app available on Github.
https://github.com/twitter/digits-android

But after following all the steps and populating every known place with API key and API secret.

My code is same I've just populated the properties file.

I'm getting: `Digits﹕ HTTP Error: 403 Forbidden, API Error: 239, User Message: Try Again`

Can anyone tell where the mistake is ?

Comment: This error indicates there is a issue with guest authentication. Are you using the consumer key and secret provided by the plugin? Keys generated by dev.twitter.com will not work.

Comment: No.  I'm using the consumer key and secret provided by twitter. 
Okay let me try bcz  I think I did that earlier too

Comment: @Rubanraj Thanks a lot man. Digit has poor/misleading documentation.
Ur insight worked flawlessly

Comment: @Rubanraj i also has the same issue but i wont able to find all three key in fabric dashboard. I got API and API secret from twitter another key from fabric .can u explain a bit as its quite confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project will not work when copied as-is. You need to replace the consumer key and secret provided in the example project with your own. You can generate your own consumer key and secret via Fabric web portal.